# Error en lista guardada en User Settings: El contenido no se guarda

Tags: c#

Tengo una Lista guardada en mi configuración de usuario, debería guardar varias cadenas, pero cuando verifico su valor (por Settings.Default.FileList) muestra que el valor es 0, cuando guardo una cadena, muestra el número de cadenas guardadas, pero cuando cambio de forma o reinicio la aplicación, vuelve a ser 0.
Editado: Ya he llamado al método .Save(); Y hasta el método Upgrade(); pero sigue igual

Comment: Añade mas información para que te puedan ayudar, especifica el código que estas usando.

Comment: @HectorLopez De hecho, olvidé mencionar que ya había invocado el método Save(); hasta intenté con el método Upgrade(); y nada, sigue igual.

Comment: Me refería a que indicaras tu código completo, para que los usuarios que visualicen tu pregunta puedan hacer pruebas, ver el flujo del programa.... indicar las excepciones (en el caso de que se produzcan) contra más detalles tu problema más gente de podrá ayudar.